# docker container cannot start when use -v command

Tags: docker

my system is centos7.8

I want to use docker to create a mysql and mount the data out

```
sudo docker run 
    --privileged=true 
    -p 3339:3306 
    --name mysql
    -v /home/hadoop/mysql/conf:/etc/mysql 
    -v /home/hadoop/mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d 
    -v /home/hadoop/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql 
    -v /home/hadoop/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf 
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword 
    -d mysql:8.0.16
```

The container was created successfully but could not be started. If i delete all -v command, the container can be started.

help

Comment: "Container could not be started".  What do you mean by that? What is the error message?

Comment: Afaik mounting a file in a folder obfuscates the content of the folder. So try to copy `conf.d` and `my.cnf` to `./conf` on host and then just mount this folder to `/etc/mysql` once.